# Prepositions before and after percentages

Tags: numbers, percentages

I'm commenting on several data of a graphic and I have a <strike>doubt</strike> question about the preposition that comes (or doesn't) before the percentage, and whether the determiner "the" has to appear before "times/ cases..."

Sentences:

> Further, (in) 73,83% of (the) times bloody is said...
>    ... while only 26,16% of (the) cases is a child...
>    We can notice that (in) 75,6% of (the) times...

Could you please give me some guidance?

Comment: Note that Anglophones almost always use a *period* (not comma) to indicate a decimal point.

Comment: while (in) only 26,16% of (the) cases (there) is a child...

Comment: @Denis: I don't think you can flag up ***there*** as "optional" in this context. It would never be acceptable to write *while only 26.16% of cases is a child*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed. Personally, I'd expand it entirely: while in only 26,16% of the cases there is a child. But I'm not an English native. :-)

Comment: It depends on what's in "...". _while in only 26.16% of the cases is a child the victim_.

Comment: Interesting that the confusion comes from the fact that "percent" isn't used literally. In theory, "50%" should translate to "50 per cent" or "50 per 100." That is, we should be able to say "50% cases show evidence of XYZ." But in practice, everyone says "50% of cases show evidence of XYZ."

Answer (score 1):

Note that whether or not `the` is used doesn't depend on the % symbol. It depends on the sentence, and `the` is used as per the normal rules.

> There's a piece of land we own. 90% of **the** land (we're talking about) is cultivated. [`The` **has** to be used]
>
> 65% of children play computer games. [Not `the children`, unless it is specified which children are we talking about].
>
> *Examples are from [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/per-cent)*

So to know whether or not `the` is needed, we'll require your whole sentences with context.

---

Same goes for `in`. It is included/omitted as per the normal rules.

Compare:

- `In` is required

  - In most of the cases, we succeeded
  - In 70% of the cases, we succeeded
- `In` is not required

  - We can notice that most of the times...
  - We can notice that 20% of the times....

Don't let the mathematical symbols confuse you. As a matter of fact, you should always write `fifty percent` instead of `50%`
.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I do use a preposition after a percentage. Here's how I would word the examples you gave:

> Further, 73.83% of the time the word "bloody" is said...
>
> ...while only 26.16% of cases
>
> ...75.6% of the time...

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as follows:
Further, in 73.83% of cases, the word bloody is said, while only 26.16% of these cases...
We can see that in 75.6% of cases...